# Generating Open Api / Swagger code partially

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, .net-core, swagger, openapi

I just started to use Open Api / Swagger in an Angular project based on .Net Core and managed to generate frontend code into `app.generated.ts` file. Although NSwag Studio generate a separate Service for frontend in that file, it will be really to complex in a certain period of time. So, I have looking an answer for the following questions:

**1.** Is there any way to split or generate separate file for each Controller as a generated Angular Service? For eaxmple if there are ControllerA and ControllerB, there will be 2 gererated file as TyepeScript service containing all the rellated code dedicated to these Controller. Is that possible by making some config changes?

**2.** If I want to split the gererated .ts file into serviceA.ts and serviceB.ts, then it does not meaningful as the next generate will recreate the related methods in the  `app.generated.ts` file. Am I wrong, or is there any possible solution if I want to split the generated code by preventing that part to from re-generation?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently generating multiple client files isn't supported yet, but [there were/are plans to do it](https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag/issues/1398).

Meanwhile you might want to consider looking into generating separated OpenApi specs and then using each one of them to generate separated clients. You could try to do this with NSwag itself (see [this wiki](https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag/wiki/Document-Processors-and-Operation-Processors#operation-processors) and comments in [this issue](https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag/issues/1273)) or other tools. Avoiding duplication while doing this will be challenging, though.

Comment: Many thanks. I also watching the last one and I hope it will be fixed in the near future. Do you use Swagger? Is it a serious problem that generated file contains all the services, models etc? Any experience about that?

Comment: For me it has never been a problem, but I see your point.
An approach I've sometimes used is creating wrappers around those generated services/clients and using them instead of using the autogenerated clients directly.
This allows me to modify the code only in one place if there's a change in the server's api, which has proven to be extremely useful in case of any change/upgrade in the generation tool, plus gives me the flexibility of splitting those wrappers into different files if appropriated and exporting only the models I need in each one of them.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just wanted to be clarified about some issues as I am new on Swagger. How many services in the generated file approximately? Do you thşnk that it is good idea to use this approach as it seems to save time for building frontend related code and API docs? I think it is also possible to use it without generating frontend code, is that true?

Comment: I've worked with ~100 autogenerated methods (~5000 lines files), grouped in ~20 different services.
I'm not sure I fully understand your second question. OpenApi/Swagger spec is enough documentation for the API itself, and it's generated independently from the clients (in fact it's a previous, required step to generated any clients). Client generation is definitely a must for me, and I would apply the manual wrapper approach on top of those generated clients if you plan to reference those generated services a lot from your frontend codebase, expect common api changes or just seek isolation.

Comment: Consuming OpenApi specs without actually generating clients is something that I may have heard at some point in the past, but cannot find any reference about it now. I wouldn't be surprised, though, since the amount of swagger-related tools out there is incredible (see [this](https://openapi.tools/), for instance).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your useful comments, I learned lots from you :) Voted up  **1)** In my question, actually I wanted to know that if you suggest to use Swagger for generating Angular front end. Because as the project is getting bigger, I am wondering if the single generated file would be a problem. **2)** On the other hand, after generating file, I think you just create related components (if you use Angular) corresponding to the newly added API methods to the Controller, am I right? Is there any changes in the generated file - if you did, it will gone after next build :(

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not that familiar Angular to give you more concrete answers about that I have only used [TypeScriptClientGenerator](https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag/wiki/TypeScriptClientGenerator) with Fetch template, which just autogenerates methods in a single file (which should not be modified) and that can be referenced from actual frontend components.
Have a deep read at [this](https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag/wiki/TypeScriptClientGenerator-Angular) and try to find some examples, but the approach seems to be similar: use the generated code, but never modify it. Good luck!